# How can I fill an NSArray dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a `for` loop. Inside that loop I want to fill up an `NSArray` with some objects. But I don't see any method that would let me do that. I know in advance how many objects there are. I want to avoid an `NSMutableArray`, since some people told me that's a very big overhead and performance-brake compared to `NSArray`.

I've got something like this:

```
NSArray *returnArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
for (imageName in imageArray) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    //Now, here I'd like to add that image to the array...
}
```

I looked in the documentation for `NSArray`, but how do I specify how many elements are going to be in there? Or must I really use `NSMutableArray` for that?

Comment: I haven't got time to look this up right now, but perhaps you need to create an NSMutableArray first, and then use a method on that to get the Immutable version? Not sure if that simply would give you an Immutable interface and no speed gain (i.e. it might be same underlying implementation as mutable), but worth a look. As far as I remember the Apple docs are clear as mud on this.

Comment: Don't listen to people who tell you that something has bad performance! NSMutableArray is a core part of Objective-C, it is highly optimised, and there is no reason to avoid it!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an `NSMutableArray`:

```
int count = [imageArray count];
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
for (imageName in imageArray) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [returnArray addObject: image];
    ...
}
```

EDIT - declaration fixed

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the data structure of the variable is of type NSArray, and not NSMutableArray? Or are those interchangeable?

Comment: NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, so it's safe.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot. Thanks! That raises another question ;)

Comment: Since it's being used as a mutable array, returnArray should be declared as an NSMutableArray. This code will work since the object really is the mutable variety, but it's bad practice (and will give a warning about NSArray not responding to addObject:).

Comment: So if that's bad practice, of course I'll do NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count]; ;)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html) for that because adding is mutation and [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) is immutable.

You could make a populated `NSMutableArray` into an `NSArray` afterwards ([see here for a discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2007/10/4/190321)) but you won't be adding items to a regular old `NSArray` anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

Would this be a good time to use an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

I know you mentioned that you would like to avoid it, but sometimes there's a reason for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise optimising only when you know `NSMutableArray` *is* causing you a performance hit but if it is, you can always create a static aray from a mutable array after you have populated it. It depends on if the performance hit is caused by you subsequent use of the `NSMutableArray` or just by creating it.

My guess is that this isn't going to be the performance bottleneck on your app.